# Moving a triangle in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to make a triangle move on the screen. Heres the class i used to define the triangle.

```
class Triangle:
    def __init__(self):
        self.points = [[100, 100],  [100, 150], [180, 125]]
        self.color = (180, 255, 100)
        self.speed = 2


    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.polygon(D, self.color, self.points)
```

I wanna be able to move the triangle. To do this i tried doing something like this

```
def move(self):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        counter = 0

        if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            for points in self.points:
                points[0][counter] += self.speed
            counter += 1
```

But i keep gettings this error `TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable`. How would i solve this problem and move the triangle? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the function move you are iterating through the list "self.points" so
the "point" variable you were trying to add to was actually just one of the points and not the full "self.points" list of points.

I think this is what you were going for:)

```
def move(self):
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    counter = 0

    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        for points in self.points:
            self.points[counter][0] += self.speed
        counter += 1
```

Another good way to do this is with enumerate.

```
def move(self):
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        for point_index,point in enumerate(self.points): 
            self.points[point_index][0] += self.speed
```

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for . Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As everyone has already answered, the issue is that the code is iterating through a list-of-lists, where the outer list simply holds the three triangle points.  So `points[0]` is the list `[100, 100]`, `points[1]` is `[100, 150]`, etc.  Your code is failing because `points[0][counter]` is only "correct" for counter < 3.  Once the counter is greater than the number of points the code fails.

You probably meant:

```
for point in self.points:
    # point is a co-ordinate: [ x, y ]
    point[0] += self.speed   # update x-coordinate of each point
```

I think it would be better to add a `move()` function to your `Triangle` class, keeping the inner-updating code within the class:

```
class Triangle:
    # ...

    def move( self, x_change, y_change ):
        """ Move each triangle point by x_change and y_change, at self.speed """
        for i, point in enumerate( self.points ):
            x, y = point
            new_x = x + ( x_change * self.speed )
            new_y = y + ( y_change * self.speed )
            self.points[i] = [ new_x, new_y ]
```

This allows a simple moving call to handle the key-press, and diagonal movement too.

```
# Movement keys
keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
if ( keys[pygame.K_UP] ):
    tri.move( 0, -1 )
if ( keys[pygame.K_DOWN] ):
    tri.move( 0,  1 )
if ( keys[pygame.K_LEFT] ):
    tri.move( -1, 0 )
if ( keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] ):
    tri.move(  1, 0 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at your data structure; you've abused it.

```
    self.points = [[100, 100],  [100, 150], [180, 125]]
    ...
    for points in self.points:
        # For the first iteration, points = [100, 100]
        points[0][counter] += self.speed
```

`points[0]` is the integer 100.  100[counter] is an invalid operation, causing your error message.
I can't tell you how to fix this, because it's not quite clear what you're trying to do with this code.  There are many examples on line of how to move an object in PyGame.